# Django ImportError - works from shell but not in runtime

Tags: python, django

*app.models*

```
from .tasks import do_something
```

*app.tasks*

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def do_something(self, id, **kwargs):
    from models import SomeModel
    from utils.general import retry

    @retry(exceptions=SomeModel.DoesNotExist, retries=5, delay=1, backoff=1.5)
    def do_something_inner(id):
        obj = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
        ...

    do_something_inner(id)
```

*utils.general*

```
class retry(object):
    ...
```

When I try to import utils.general manually it works (from utils.general import retry), but when do_something() is run I get an ImportError exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/local.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    __call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 420, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/proj/app/tasks.py", line 16, in do_something
    from utils.general import retry
ImportError: No module named general
```

**EDIT 1**
Adding the tree output:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tasks.pyc
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
├── urls.py
├── urls.pyc
├
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── general.py
│   ├── general.pyc
```

Comment: Could you provide `tree` output?

Comment: @f43d65 sure, see above

Comment: This may be a case of circular import. Do you have any imports from models.py or tasks.py on the top level of your utils.py?

Answer (score 0):

Just guess.

```
from .utils.general import retry
```

or

```
from ..utils.general import retry
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this, I had a utils.py within app/ and also the utils/ app. So the import was going to the wrong module. Fixed it by renaming app/utils.py